# Multi-module maven microservices deploy to Heroku

Tags: docker, maven, heroku, microservices

I have a microservices project with a parent POM and all the other modules with an internal POM.

Locally, if I run **mvn clean install -DskipTests** everything works.

I want to deploy all the microservices to Heroku, how can i do this?

The project works also for Docker & Kubernetes, is there a way to integrate also Docker in Heroku?

So it will be beautiful if I can deploy all the microservices as 1 project in Heroku, with every microservices as a Docker image.

**Thank you in advance!**

**This is an example of my project:**

[image]

**Parent POM:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.petcare</groupId>
  <artifactId>website-petcare-backend</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>parent-pom</name>
  <modules>
    <module>apiGateway</module>
    <module>reservationService</module>
    <module>userService</module>
    <module>eurekaServer</module>
    <module>mapService</module>
    <module>authService</module>
  </modules>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Build**

You can build all images for the sub-modules using the `docker-maven-plugin`.

Each sub-module must have its own Dockerfile, then in the parent POM add:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.38.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When running `mvn clean package docker:build` all projects are built and Dockerized

**Deploy**

Deploying all images (each image into its own web Dyno) is a little bit more complicated. You have few options:

1. **Script from the command line**: typically you can push the image with the following commands

   ```
     heroku container:push web -a appname
     heroku container:release web a appname
   ```

You could build a script that performs those steps for each and (very important) performs both the `heroku login` and `heroku:container login` using the credentials

2. **Using heroku.yml** where you can define at once all the containers to be deployed. It is a good approach but you need to `git push` your changes (see [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml))
3. **Use CI/CD application like Github Actions**. In this case your workflow compiles, tests, builds and pushes the application.
   This is my preferred approach: you can decide when to build/deploy (on master push? manually?), you save the Heroku credentials as secrets, you can automate the release pipeline.
   You can read more [here](https://medium.com/geekculture/deploy-to-heroku-from-a-macbook-m1-heroku-cli-or-githubactions-868bc3a50935)

You can also try the [Heroku Docker Maven plugin](https://github.com/gcatanese/heroku-docker-maven-plugin) if you like to control all services using Maven